# Laravel form model binding with double one-to-one relationship error

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, relationship

So after fiddling about for a day I feel like I kind of hit a wall, and would like to get some pointers. I have a rather normal user table in my database, where each user has the option of 2 addresses (one for billing and one for receiving). In my form this goes rather decent with form model binding, where I can use Blade code like below to generate proper fields:

```
{{ Form::text('billing[city]') }}
{{ Form::text('receiving[city]') }}
```

In similar fashion, I can see the results in the controller through the use of:

```
$billing = $user->billing;
$billing->city = Input::get('billing.city');

$receiving = $user->receiving;
$receiving->city = Input::get('receiving.city');
```

Now the issue that I'm having is if I save all 3 models separately, as in `$user->save();`, `$billing->save();` and `$receiving->save();`, I'll have 3 separate error groups. Normally this would be fine since I could just merge them together into one large MessageBag, but in this case any error made in either of the Addresses wouldn't list if it was from the billing address or from the receiving address. Instead my error will just have the key `city` instead of `billing.city` like I'd prefer it to be.

The MessageBag class does not seem to support a method for prefixing all the contents or something similar, and it doesn't seem that wise to me to just add a method inside of the already existing class, as that would break my errors if we decide to update Laravel in the future.

Any kind of pointers or help would be appreciated, I'm mostly using this project to get the hang of Laravel, so a wildly different approach is very welcome as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the validation class for all the input in one go before you even start calling the save methods?

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using Ardent for validation, so the call to save() also does the validation of the model. Although you do bring up a good point, validating beforehand would allow me to manually separate the errors. I am still rather curious if there would be another way to solve it though, that way I can keep my validation running in similar fashion for everything :).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ardent, but perhaps associating the addresses and using push which should save everything will return to you one MessageBag with all the things.

```
// Create User
$user = new User;
$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->email = Input::get('email');

// Create addresses
$billing = $user->billing;
$billing->city = Input::get('billing.city');

$receiving = $user->receiving;
$receiving->city = Input::get('receiving.city');

$user->address()->associate($billing);
$user->address()->associate($receiving);
$user->push();
```

Comment: It appears that Ardent has it's limitations there.. The way it usually works is if you just call `$user->save();`, it will also trigger the validation using a set of rules that you can list in your model. If validation goes wrong, the result of `$user->save();` will be a boolean false, and errors can be accessed through `$user->errors();`. When using `$user->push();` it does indeed seem to properly save the relations, but the MessageBag available through `$user->errors();` won't include the errors of the relations sadly. Thanks for the help though, it gives me some helpfull alternatives :).